Why is adding another simple constructor make a simple class not a literal type anymore?
Just adding MyPair(const A& first, const B& second) function make the "MyPair" not a literal type anymore.
Why?
template <class A,class B> class MyPair  {
    public: A first; B second;
    public: using type_first=A;
    public: using type_second=B;
    MyPair() = default;   

    ///vvv remove this constructor make "MyPair" a literal type
    MyPair(const A& first, const B& second)  
   
        : first(first),
        second(second) {
    }

};

int main(){
    constexpr MyPair<int,int> ssss=[](){return  MyPair<int,int>{5,3};}();
    ///: ^ fail to compile
}

A type is a literal type if it is:


(no) a scalar type; or
(no) a reference type; or
(no) an array of literal type; or
(yes?) a class type (Clause 9) that has all of the following properties:

(yes) it has a trivial destructor,
(yes) every constructor call and full-expression in the brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members (if any) is a
constant expression (5.19),
(yes?) it is an aggregate type (8.5.1) or has at least one constexpr constructor or constructor template that is not a copy or
move constructor, and
(yes) all of its non-static data members and base classes are of literal types.




I love constexpr, but still lack understanding about literal type.
Additional experiment...
Without the problematic constructor, this code (same result) surprisingly works.
It actually do the same thing, and it is what I want and expect.
constexpr MyPair<int,int> ssss2=[](){
    MyPair<int,int> re=MyPair<int,int>{};re.first=5;return re;
}();

It makes me confuse.  Compiler takes a grudge against non-default constructor?

Well, you cannot call a non-constexpr constructor when initializing a constexpr variable, for obvious reason.

This is a comment not an answer because Iʼm not certain, but I believe adding the second constructor makes it no longer an aggregate type.  That line is now trying to call the constructor you provided, which is not constexpr.

@Daniel H  :: Thanks, why is the problematic constructor not constexpr?  It looks so constexpr to me.  (I add a lambda that does a similar thing to the question. Compiler thinks it is constexpr)

@cppBeginner -- your ctor not constexpr, change it to constexpr MyPair(const A& first, const B& second) and it will compile.

@cppBeginner -- your second lambda is different, it uses a default ctor, not the two parameter ctor.

@Gene :: Thanks, it works. But why?

@cppBeginner Because you made the ctor constexpr. How do you expect to use a non-constexpr function in a constexpr context?

This has nothing to do with literal type. You jist can't use a non constexpe function in a constexpr context.

"Additional experiment" C++ should not be learnt by trial and error or experiments. Instead a good c++ book should be used.

@Alex :: I must obey.  My book is too old.

@cppBeginner “Thanks, why is the problematic constructor not constexpr” Because while you can look at it and say itʼs constexpr, the compiler cannot; it needs to be explicitly told.  Put the keyword constexpr in front of the constructor or the compiler will think it needs to be run at runtime.

The program will work if you make the constructor taking 2 arguments constexpr:
constexpr MyPair(const A& first, const B& second);

If the parameterized constructor is not constexpr it cannot be used in a constexpr context.
